# Does loading a product using Mage::getModel('catalog/product') give out error messages if nothing is found?

Tags: product-attribute, ce-1.9.1.0

for a relaunch I've been trying to output some 301 redirect for our htaccess (the old system was not magento).

So I've exported an array of `'old_url' => 'product_id'` and now I'm trying to loop through it to get our new urls, using something like this:

```
foreach($arr as $url => $prodId) {

    $oldurl = $url;

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->setStoreId($store_id)
                ->loadByAttribute('objektnummer', $prodId);

    $newurl = $product->getProductUrl();            

    echo "Redirect 301 " . $oldurl . "\t\t" . $newurl . "\n";

}
```

But what I've found is that if a Produkt is not found, the loop breaks. Obviously this is rather tedious if you have 10,000s of URLs to go through.

So my question is this, if loading a product by a product_id that is not found in the database breaks the loop, how can I check it first?

It would be nice if the following returned 'FALSE' or 'NULL' or something rather than just breaking.

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($store_id)
            ->loadByAttribute('objektnummer', $prodId);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute following code

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->setStoreId($store_id)
        ->loadByAttribute('objektnummer', $prodId);
```

Magento returns object of the product, or if there no such product magento returns FALSE. And the error in your case appear on the next row:

```
$newurl = $product->getProductUrl();
```

Because FALSE has no method getProductUrl()

So in that case just check:

```
        if($product !== false)
        {
            $newurl = $product->getProductUrl();
        }
```

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for. I did try and check for true / null and false, but I couldn't get it to work. This works perfectly. I suppose it should as I guess it is not much different to `if(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($store_id)->loadByAttribute('objektnummer', $prodId)) {` apart from that the call isn't made twice.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
foreach($arr as $url => $prodId) {

$oldurl = $url;

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->setStoreId($store_id)
            ->loadByAttribute('objektnummer', $prodId);

if ($newurl = $product->getProductUrl()) {            
    echo "Redirect 301 " . $oldurl . "\t\t" . $newurl . "\n";
}
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid this behaves exactly the same and breaks as soon as it gets to a `$prodId` that it can not find.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: <b>Fatal error</b>:  Call to a member function getProductUrl() on a non-object in <b>/html/magento/_do301.php</b> on line <b>4683</b><br /> - The line in question is `if($newurl = $product->getProductUrl()) {`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got round it by doing this:

```
foreach($arr as $url => $prodId) {

    $oldurl = $url;

    if(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->setStoreId($store_id)->loadByAttribute('objektnummer', $prodId)) {

        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                    ->setStoreId($store_id)
                    ->loadByAttribute('objektnummer', $prodId);


        $newurl = $product->getProductUrl();

        echo "Redirect 301 " . $oldurl . "\t\t" . $newurl . "\n";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It will good idea to use Product collection and filter the collection by products ids.
 then add Url rewrite manage .it does not break system

```
$ReverseIndex=array();
foreach($arr as $key=>$value):
$ReverseIndex[$value]=$key;
endforeach;


$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addUrlRewrite()->addIdFilter(array_values($arr));

foreach($collection  as $eachPro):
if($ReverseIndex[$eachPro->getId]==$eachPro->getProductUrl()):
 echo "Redirect 301 " . $ReverseIndex[$eachPro->getId] . "\t\t" .$eachPro->getProductUrl() . "\n";
endif;

endforeach;
```

According you comment as you want to filter using attribute then you can used in condition to collection

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->addUrlRewrite()->addAttributeToFilter('objektnummer',array('in' => explode(',', array_values($arr))));
```

**But make sure the attribute is enable at Used In Product at Attribute backed**

Comment: Nice, but I am not using the actual product ids, I'm using a custom product attribute 'objektnummer'.

Comment: I suppose I could have used `->addAttributeToFilter('objektnummer', $prodId); ` on the collection instead of `->addIdFilter()`. Thanks.

Comment: please check my update answer

Comment: Remove the explode from your code, it already is an array.